# strcasecomp doesn't work in my code

Tags: c

I want to make a program which are sorting input lines. There is an argument "-f". This in case you want to compare strings and every upper character to be seen as a lower during comparison. For this I used strcasecomp function. But it is not working. Also to understand my code "-n" is in case you want to sort them numerically instead of lexicographically and -r for a reverse sort. If I need to post more code please tell me.

For exaple I do this:

```
sort -f
a
A
```

the expected result should be:

```
a
A
```

but I get

```
A
a
```

This my main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nlines; /* number of input lines read */
    int numeric = 0; /* 1 if numeric sort */
    int reverse = 0;
    int foldupper = 0;
    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-n") == 0)
        numeric = 1;
    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-r") == 0)
        reverse = 1;
    if (argc > 2 && strcmp(argv[2], "-r") == 0)
        reverse = 1;
    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-f") == 0)
        foldupper = 1;
    if (argc > 2 && strcmp(argv[2], "-f") == 0)
        foldupper = 1;
    if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0)
    {
         if(reverse == 0 && numeric == 1)
        {
            crescsort((void**) lineptr, 0, nlines-1,(int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));

        }
        else if(reverse == 0 && numeric == 0)
        {
            //bug here?
            crescsort((void**) lineptr, 0, nlines-1,(int (*)(void*,void*))(foldupper ? strcasecmp : strcmp));
        }
       else if ( reverse == 1 && numeric == 0  )
        {
            //or here?
            descsort((void**) lineptr, 0, nlines-1,(int (*)(void*,void*))(foldupper ? strcasecmp : strcmp));
        }

        writelines(lineptr, nlines);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("input too big to sort\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And this is the sort function

```
void crescsort(void *v[], int left, int right,int (*comp)(void *, void *))
{
    int i, last;
    void swap(void *v[], int , int );
    if (left >= right) /* do nothing if array contains */
        return; /* fewer than two elements */
    swap(v, left, (left + right)/2);
    last = left;
    for (i = left+1; i <= right; i++)
    if ((*comp)(v[i], v[left]) < 0)
        swap(v, ++last, i);
    swap(v, left, last);
    crescsort(v, left, last-1, comp);
    crescsort(v, last+1, right, comp);
}
```

Comment: How is the second `if()` in `if(reverse == 0){}else if(reverse == 0 && numeric == 0){}` *ever* supposed to be reached?

Comment: thanks for i've changed but is still not working.

Comment: Are you sure `crescsort()` is a stable sort?

Comment: I don't see `strcasecomp` in your code,

Comment: yes i think it is a problem in if staments i think i miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically a == A if you ignore case. So both results

```
A
a
```

and

```
a
A
```

are correct (because they are equivalent). You are in fact sorting a list with 2 entries a and a. Seems like you expect order of equal keys to be preserved, most sorts dont guarantee that. Why not write a sort that does preserve order :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `crescsort()` in that it does not guarantee the original order if elements compared are equal.

> Unstable sorting algorithms can be specially implemented to be stable. One way of doing this is to artificially extend the key comparison, so that comparisons between two objects with otherwise equal keys are decided using the order of the entries in the original input list as a tie-breaker. Remembering this order, however, may require additional time and space. Wikipedia ref [Stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)

To fix, change `crescsort()`.

It is not a `strcasecmp()` issue.